# Remove item from Menu Strip

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Menu Strip in **Windows Forms** with the following structure, named `mstMain`:

- File
- Programs

  - Address
  - Contacts
  - - PRG1001
  - - PRG1002
  - Query
  - Settings
  - - PRG8003
- Help

And I'm doing a `for` loop to remove all items in `Programs` (named `mnuPrograms`) where the number of items is `== 0`. My attempt is:

```
  for (int n = 0; n < mnuPrograms.MenuItems.Count; n++)
                        if (mnuPrograms.MenuItems[n].MenuItems.Count == 0)
                            mnuPrograms.MenuItems.Remove(mnuPrograms.MenuItems[n]);
```

And it doesn't remove the correct items. I have used `foreach` too:

```
foreach (
     MenuItem item in
       mnuPrograms.MenuItems.Cast<MenuItem>().Where(item => item.MenuItems.Count == 0))
                        mnuPrograms.MenuItems.Remove(item);
```

But in this case I receive a **`InvalidOperationException`**. How can I perform this?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I debugged it and it performs OK in my first attempt, but the result is unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Usability point of view, you might prefer to disable the items. Users want to see that they cannot do something. By removing them they may get confused. Once you disable the items your problem might already be solved.

**EDIT:**

You also have a false assumption that denotes a deeper misunderstanding. You are doing two things:

- iterating over a set
- modifying the set

You shouldn't do both because termination conditions become unpredictable (NP-incomplete under circumstances) if you don't have an **invariant** set over which you enumerate. That's why a `foreach` will throw an exception if you modify the enumerated set inside the block.

To avoid this you should increment only when you don't remove, but at that point a `while()` is more elegant, much like this:

```
while (i < list.Count)
{
    // do stuff with list[i]

    if (removal_condition) // only do one of these, never both
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen that in a second re-read. There is some more code now that should explain what you were missing :)

Answer (score 3):

You are modifiying the list while you are looping through it.

- In the **for** clause, the indexes change when you remove an item.
  Try looping through the list from the end to the start.
- In the **foreach** clause, modifying a list while enumerating it ends
  with an **InvalidOperationException**.

And [pid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3227403/pid) is right, you may disable an item rather than delete it.

Comment: Look there... I've edited my answer while you were writing yours :)